# How to access clipboard data using Accessibility in Android 10?

Tags: android

I know that access to the clipboard data has been blocked since Android 10

However, I found that a specific clipboard app uses the Accessibility function to fetch the clipboard data.

How can I get clipboard data using Accessibility?

Comment: Just use [`android-clipboardmanager`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-clipboardmanager).

Answer (score -1):

This way can copy text to clipboard.

```
// get views id first and the format like this "com.google.authenticator:id/tv_main"    
public void inputText(List<String> viewIds, String text){
    AccessibilityNodeInfo root = getRootInActiveWindow();
    if(root == null) return;

    for (String id : viewIds){
        final List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = root.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId(id);
        if(list != null && !list.isEmpty()){
            AccessibilityNodeInfo info = list.get(0);
            // Clipboard
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", text);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

            CharSequence txt = info.getText();
            if(txt == null) txt = "";

            // worked in >= Android 5.0
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, txt);
                info.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_FOCUS);
                info.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He asked how to access it (meaning read from it), not how to copy something to it.